# 12VDC from two different 230Vac voltage sources

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, ac-dc

I want 12VDC from two different AC source such as Main and DG supply. At a time only one source will be present. Right now I am using the circuit as shown below.
[image: 230VAC to 12VDC]

Is there a way to replace two transformer considering 12Vdc, 200mA output current?

One way is to use capacitive power using resistor and capacitor but I have never tried it and not sure about it`s reliability.

**Updates after your comments:**

Reason I am looking for alternate solution is

1. I want to reduce total cost. Looking for less than 2 USD solution.
2. Very limited space available to fit this transformer on PCB, so I want to avoid customized transformer.

Any suggestion on this will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Do you need isolation from the 230Vac?

Comment: If you can guarantee that only one source will be present at a time, just have them both input to the same port.

Comment: No, it is not guaranteed. Both supply can be present for some amount of time. Non Isolation based suggestions are acceptable.

Comment: Then it’s entirely dependent on how they are built. If you want to make sure, you need to put a diode (preferably low Vf Schottky) in series with each power supply.

Comment: Are you trying to eliminate *both* transformers, or just reduce to one?  What safety requirements to you have to meet? (e.g. UL 1008)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution would be to have only one DC power supply and an electromagnetic DPDT relay or contactor to change it over from mains power to DG.